# Не отображается русский в сообщениях полученных из системных команд

Tags: кодировка, pycharm

Когда я получаю сообщения в консоли из докера или других системных сообщений, то получаю краказябры. Причём вывод из программы на русском работает. В windows консоли стоит кодовая стоит 866 кодовая страница и utf-8 на powershell.
[image: Отображение консоли]

Comment: Зачем вам вообще `os.system("pause")`, если через pycharm запускаете? Если нужно чтобы при запуске из проводника не закрывалась консоль, сделайте просто `input("Нажмите Enter...")`

Comment: Вопрос был в другом. Это для примера написал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще всего будет нажать на название запускаемого файла справа в самом верху. После выбрать `Edit configuration -> Execution -> Emulate terminal in output console` (Поставить галочку.)

Comment: Сегодня попробую

Comment: Проверил. Действительно, при установке этого параметра, оно выводит Русский нормально.

Comment: Правда, хотелось бы знать почему так происходит

Comment: @MrMarvel этот параметр заставляет pycharm эмулировать командную строку т.е. все команды которые работают нормально в cmd будут работать и здесь. Почему он  ошибается в кодировке без этого параметра я не знаю.